# Nhibernate One To Many With Criteria

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I've got a class which contains a list of associated objects.

I've map it as follows:

```
<class name="MyDto" table="`MyView`" mutable="false"  lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <set name="Days" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
          <key column="Id" />
          <one-to-many class="MyAssociatedObj"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="MyAssociatedObj" table="V_SC_NEED" mutable="false" lazy="false" >
    <id name="Id"  column="`ID2`" type="int">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property type="DateTime" not-null="true" name="DayDate"  column="`Date`" />

    <component name="Audit">
        <property type="string" not-null="true" length="255" name="Username" column="`USERNAME`" />
        <property type="decimal" not-null="true" name="PreviousValue" column="`PrevVal`" />
    </component>
</class>
```

What I wanted to do is to get a list of MyDto Object, filtering by my associated object, MyAssociatedObject.

Which means, for example, if i do:

```
UnitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<MyDto>().List<MyDto>()
```

I get a list of 42 lines.
Now, I want to filter them by my associated object, by a restriction of between.
the problem is that when i do so:

```
UnitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<MyDto>().CreateAlias("Days", "days").Add(Restrictions.Between("days.DayDate", query.FromDate, query.ToDate));
```

I'm getting, somehow 684 rows ! (some cartesial product or something).

Any advise?
Many thanks !

Comment: can you post your equals method of MyDto?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting more rows in the second query because you are **JOINing** with `MyAssociatedObj`, which seems to be in a *many-to-one* relationship with your `MyDTO` class.
If you want to filter out duplicates of `MyDTO`, you can use the DistinctRootResultTransformer:

```
UnitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<MyDto>().CreateAlias("Days", "days")  
   .Add(Restrictions.Between("days.DayDate", query.FromDate, query.ToDate))  
   .SetResultTransformer(  
          new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
```

Hope it helps.